# How can jQuery convert my ordered list into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>Kawasaki</li>
    <li>Vauxhall</li>
</ol>
```

What is the jQuery function that will transform the list items into an array?

```
var cars;
$('li').map(function() {
    // converts the ordered list into a javascript array named 'cars'
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you want is an array of the li DOM elements you can just use jQuery's [toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
var cars = $('li').toArray();
```

If what you need is an array containing ['audi', 'kawasaki',...] then:

```
var cars = [];
$('li').each(function(i, elem) {
    cars.push($(elem).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to find out how to create the array from the contents and not the entire li DOM elements

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li').map(function() { 
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```